# Tracing/finding function calls and arguments made by an AppKit class method

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos, appkit

Suppose I'm calling class method + (NSStatusBar *)systemStatusBar:

```
NSStatusBar *sB;

sB=[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar];
```

My question is what's the best way to trace that class method call and find out what it is calling in terms of other methods and arguments?

Does this entail advanced disassembly beyond what XCode provides?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DTrace, which is behind the Instruments. See an excellent introduction in [this MacTech article](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.23/23.11/ExploringLeopardwithDTrace/index.html).